# Cómo transferir un archivo del PC al móvil con python

Tags: python, android, python-3.x

He querido hacer un programa en el que puedes descargar música de YT al PC y lo he conseguido. También quise crear una funcionalidad de que si tienes un móvil conectado al PC puedas elegir si descargar esa música al móvil, pero esto no le he conseguido ya que me da error.

Así funciona lo que hice:

1. Descarga la música en una carpeta del pc
2. Con la librería "shutil" muevo de ruta el archivo de música.
3. Cierro el programa.

Me da el error "filenotfounderror errno 2 no such file or directory".
Este error es debido a que la ruta marcada es una ruta del móvil; ya que, cuando pongo una ruta del ordenador sí funciona.

```
source = parent_dir + '\\video\\' + nombre1 + '.mp4'
destination = "Este equipo\\Redmi 8\\Almacenamiento interno compartido\\Download\\" + nombre1 + ".mp4"
shutil.move(source, destination)
```

Comment: El hecho de que conectes el móvil y veas los archivos en el File Manager no quiere decir que el móvil esté montado a nivel de Sistema Operativo. Si tienes Linux, por ejemplo, `mount` no muestra que el móvil esté montado. Por tanto, no puedo ejecutar comandos como `cp`, `mv`, `ls` o `rm`. Sin embargo, si lo ves vía File Manager, pues este tiene un *plugin* específico para acceder al móvil.

Comment: Añadiendo info adicional al comentario de arriba, los nombres de los directorios que ves en tu teléfono son muy diferentes a lo que tu escribiste. Por ejemplo: `sdcard/emulated/0/downloads` está podría ser **por ejemplo** la ruta a descargas del almacenamiento externo. Repito, es solo un ejemplo ilustrativo puede diferir de la realidad.